# Running hive query using shell script

Tags: linux, bash, sed, hive

I have a hive query that is working fine. but when I want to run this in a shell script I am unable to make it to work.

Below is the shell script.

```sh
#!/bin/bash    

start_date='2019-08-01'
end_date='2019-08-31'

while IFS='|' read -r table_name val;
do
     hive -e "set hive.cli.print.header=true;select source_to_date, target_count from testing.log_final where project_name= '${val}' and source_to_date between '${start_date}' and '${end_date}' order by source_to_date;" | sed 's/[\t]/,/g'  > /x/home/SUER/btree/"${table_name}".csv

done < /x/home/"$USER"/bt_tables.txt
```

Contents of `bt_tables.txt`:

```
merchants|102_merchants_project
payments|103_payments_project
```

Query that works fine:

```
hive -e "set hive.cli.print.header=true;select source_to_date, target_count from testing.log_final where project_name= '102_merchants_project' and source_to_date between '2019-08-01' and '2019-08-31' order by source_to_date;" | sed 's/[\t]/,/g'  > /x/home/SUER/btree/merchants.csv
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Do you have any error message ?

Comment: @howie There is no error but the file created is empty. I am expecting data in the file

Comment: You mean **/x/home/SUER/btree/merchants.csv ** is empty ? Do you try without sed ?

Comment: @howie yes That file is empty and the query is also not returning any results. Looks like the while loop is not working as expected

Comment: "Query that works fine" - by fine, you mean that it returns data?

Comment: @mangusta Yes It returns data

Comment: add echo to check what hive command is being built, like this: `echo  "hive -e set hive.cli.print.header=true; d select source_to_date, target_count from testing.log_final where project_name='${val}' and source_to_date between '${start_date}' and '${end_date}' order by source_to_date;" `

Comment: Store your hive command into a variable and echo that variable into the desired file

Eg, `hive_var =$(hive -e "set hive.cli.print.header=true;select source_to_date, target_count from testing.log_final where project_name= '102_merchants_project' and source_to_date between '2019-08-01' and '2019-08-31' order by source_to_date;" | sed 's/[\t]/,/g' )`
`echo $hive_var > /x/home/SUER/btree/"${table_name}".csv`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your given command may be ok, but you are redirecting in your output file, not appending.

See *man bash*

```
Redirecting Output
   Redirection  of output causes the file whose name results from the expansion of word to be opened for writing
   on file descriptor n, or the standard output (file descriptor 1) if n is not specified.  If the file does not
   exist it is created; if it does exist it is truncated to zero size.

   The general format for redirecting output is:

          [n]>word
```

You can use append redirect output with >> or write to your file after the end of while execution

```
Appending Redirected Output
   Redirection of output in this fashion causes the file whose name results from the expansion  of  word  to  be
   opened  for appending on file descriptor n, or the standard output (file descriptor 1) if n is not specified.
   If the file does not exist it is created.

   The general format for appending output is:

          [n]>>word
```

In your case :

```
while IFS='|' read -r table_name val;
do
     hive -e "cmd"  >> /x/home/SUER/btree/"${table_name}".csv
done < /x/home/"$USER"/bt_tables.txt
```

or

```
while IFS='|' read -r table_name val;
do
     hive -e "cmd"
done < /x/home/"$USER"/bt_tables.txt >/x/home/SUER/btree/"${table_name}".csv
```

IHTH